# how to write the Criteria query for taking the person list more than the age is 50 from

Tags: hibernate

in person table dateofbirth column is there, i want to take the list more than the age is 50.
I have written the sql query 
But I need to write Criteria Query

**mysqlquery is**

```
 select dateofbirth,datediff(now(),dateofbirth)/325 as age FROM     test_hibernate1.person where datediff(now(),dateofbirth)/325>50;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a jodaTime to easly change a currentDate to currentDate - 50 years

```
DateTime currentDate = new DateTime();
Date dateMinusFiftyYears = currentDate.minusYears(50).toDate();
criteria.add(Restrictions.le("dateOfBirth", dateMinusFiftyYears));
```

try something like this.